# Joining a pair of lines with specific starting points

Tags: linux, sed

I know that with sed I can print

```
cat current.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/,/'  > new.txt
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

to

```
A,B
C,D
E,F
```

What I would like to do is following:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

to

```
A,D
B,E
C,F
```

I'd like to join 1 with 4, 2 with 5, 3 with 6 and so on.
Is this possible with sed? Any idea how it could be achieved?

Thank you.

Comment: What if there are 8 lines in the file? Is it still 1 with 4, or is it 1 with 5, 2 with 6...?

Comment: It should be 1 with 5, 2 with 6, 3 with 7 and 4 with 8.
Thanks! Also for the formatting :)

Comment: @user3504232 Is the file guaranteed to have an even number of lines?

Comment: @Mike Yes, it is guaranteed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try printing in columns:

```
pr -s, -t -2 current.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is longer than I was hoping, but:

```
$ lc=$(( $(wc -l current.txt | sed 's/ .*//') / 2 ))
$ paste <(head -"$lc" current.txt) <(tail -"$lc" current.txt) | column -t -o,
```

The variable `lc` stores the number of lines in `current.txt` divided by two. Then `head` and `tail` are used to print `lc` first and `lc` last lines, respectively (i.e. the first and second half of the file); then `paste` is used to put the two together and `column` changes tabs to commas.

Comment: FWIW if you use "wc -l <current.txt" in place of "wc -l current.txt" you don't need the `sed` because `wc` doesn't output the filename...

Comment: Thank you also, works great but @Scrutinizer's solution is just too nice ;)

Comment: @user3504232 Of course it is! Obviously that is the true answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} NR>3 {print a[NR-3]","$0}' current.txt
A,D
B,E
C,F
```

This solution is easy to adjust if you like other interval.
Just change `NR>3` and `NR-3` to desired number.